# Matlab builder JA: Problems with accessing builder JA

Tags: matlab

First of all I would like to thank you for any kind of help, I try to be as clear as possible.

If I want to use MATLAB builder JA via `deploytool`, I have there no option to create JAVA package in `deploytool` GUI. I suppose that I have something wrong with settings but don't know which step exactly.

So first of all I Install **MATLAB 2013a** with **MATLAB builder JA Version 2.2.6**, I had to install corresponding version of Matlab Compiler Runtime (version v8.1) and also windows SDK 7.1. It is necessary to have proper version of JDK corresponding to Matlab version,  so when I use command in Matlab:

```
version -java
"Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode"
```

So I downloaded proper version of JDK (x64bit same like my OS and MATLAB version are).
Setup a JAVA_HOME path (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17) in environment variable, and also add a custom path to "Path" variable in my case:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin;
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\runtime\win64;
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v81\runtime\win64;
```

So then when I type in MATLAB `getenv JAVA_HOME` I get a right path to JAVA installation, but when I type again **version  -java** I get same response like I had with no  installation of JDK. When I try to write **javac -version** command in Matlab, I get this response:

> "Undefined function 'javac' for input arguments of type 'char'."

I also type this commands in my command line in windows, and the result was good:

```
"java version "1.6.0_17'
```

Java(TM) SE Runtime Enviroment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.3.-b01, mixed mode)"

In the ideal scenario i should get same response in matlab but I don't and I have absolutely no idea why.
I was reading lots of material about it and no one has the same problem. I tried matlab 2013b too with another licence, MCR, and JDK (1.7.0_11) but with same result.

What am I doing wrong? please help.. thank you very much

Comment: When you have MATLAB installed, it is not necessary to install the MCR or setup JAVA_HOME.  MATLAB comes with it's own Java installed. I don't know what to expect from MATLAB builder JA, but do not think you need to override the Java installation.

Comment: Yes, you were right. Matlab has it's own JDE. When I tried the same command with "!" at start, it gives me same result as in cmd. But the reason why I wrote this question was that I was unable to reach Builder JA via "deploytool". Thare was no option "create Java package". And that was licensy issue. None of three faculty licenses did not contain Builder JA, but it was installed physically.
Anyway, thank you very much for time spend with this answer, you are very kind. Thank you again.

Comment: I would love to see an answer here!